# Typescript: How to make type that accepts object which keys match generic but all values are map functions of value argument

Tags: typescript, types, typescript-typings, type-inference, typescript-generics

I want to achieve type that says: "I have all keys recursively same as type **T** but all my values are function that accept such key value and map it.

I've tried the code below but it doesn't infer return types of specified functions and recursiveness is wrong

```
export type ObjectButAllKeyIsValueFn<T> = {
    [K in keyof T]?: ObjectButAllKeyIsValueFn<T[K]> | (<R>(value: T[K]) => R)
}


interface User {
    name: string,
    surname: string,
    address: {
        city: string,
        country: string,
        street: string
    }
}

const z: ObjectButAllKeyIsValueFn<User> = {
    name: value => `Hello ${value}`,
    address: {
        city: city => 1
    }
};
```

Update: 
I want to achieve something like this but recursive, so I have to properly map StupidPattern to Pattern

```
type StupidPattern<T> = {
    [K in keyof T]: StupidPattern<T[K]> | ((value: T[K]) => unknown)
}

type Pattern<T> = {
    [K in keyof T]: (value: T[K]) => unknown
}

type Result<T, P = Pattern<T>> = {
    [K in keyof P]: K extends keyof T
        ? P[K] extends (value: T[K]) => infer R
            ? R
            : never
        : never
}

declare function map <T> (pattern: Pattern<T>): (target: T) => Result<T, Pattern<T>>
declare function map <T> (pattern: Pattern<T>, target: T): Result<T, Pattern<T>>;
```

Comment: `((value: T[K]) => T[K])` the return value needs to be the same as the argument if I am understanding you correctly

Comment: @Marv no its not, you can map value to any type, but I want to preserve that type in an argument and on resulting object have a proper typing

Answer (score 1):

The type `(<R>(value: T[K]) => R)` is not what you are looking for; essentially the generic `R` is [quantified](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantifier_(logic)) the wrong way.  It means "a function whose input is of type `T[K]` and whose output is any type `R` that the *caller* specifies.  That's not really possible to implement safely.  Presumably you really mean that the *implementer* of the function should be able to specify `R`, but there's no clean way in TypeScript to represent that with generics... you'd maybe put `R` as another generic parameter of `ObjectButAllKeyIsValueFn`, but then you'd need one `R` per key of `T`.  Let's back up and look at this a different way:

How about we define `ObjectButAllKeyIsValueFun` as this type:

```
export type ObjectButAllKeyIsValueFn<T> = {
  [K in keyof T]?: ObjectButAllKeyIsValueFn<T[K]> | ((value: T[K]) => unknown)
}
```

This type captures the idea that function-valued properties are allowed to return absolutely any type as long as you're concerned.  But of course, simply annotating a value as type `ObjectButallKeyIsValueFn<User>` would throw away a bunch of information about that value's type; you wouldn't know what type each function returns, or even if any particular property is a function at all.

So let's give up on *annotating* variables as that type.  Instead, when we create values, we make sure they are *assignable* to that type without widening them.  This will give us all the IntelliSense you want.  Here's a helper function and its application to `User`:

```
const asObjType = <T>() => <U extends ObjectButAllKeyIsValueFn<T>>(u: U) => u;

const asObjUser = asObjType<User>();
```

And here's how you call `asObjUser()`:

```
const z = asObjUser({
  name: value => `Hello ${value}`,
  address: {
    city: city => 1
  }
});

/* const z: {
    name: (value: string) => string;
    address: {
        city: (city: string) => number;
    };
} */

console.log(z.name("Fred")); // Hello Fred
```

That works and keeps track of the specific type of `z`.  It also catches errors like this:

```
const oops = asObjUser({
  name: 123, // error!
  // number is not assignable to string | ((value: string) => unknown) | undefined
});
```

So, hopefully that's enough for you to make progress.  Good luck!

[Playground link to code](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#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-RzwpEYnEj3Bwr1gJplPXNUigA)

Comment: I cannot get how you use such curried function and get type properly. Actually I have my code running properly at js but cannot annotate and rewrite it in typescript. The aim I want to achieve is a function that allows to map values via their structure declaration mapping. So in my I have some pattern object whose keys are exactly the same as target value I want to map, but values are functions that accept target "object" values and map them. Also the problem is that I use here recursive mapping and it's very difficult to write recursive type :P

Comment: I don't really understand this comment, nor do I see the issue in your edited code.  Could you make sure it's a [mcve] that clearly demonstrates the issue you're having? Good luck!